# Color of canvas wont change. Using screens

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

### I got the answer while writing this. Still gonna post if someone has same issue

This code was supposed to change the color of the canvas of my `Led` object, but for some reason it doesn't. I don't get any error messages.

Python code:

```
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class PrincipalPage(Screen):
    pass


class ConfigPage(Screen):
    pass

class PrincipalWidget(Widget):
    # Dict responsible for getting the specified powers from json file
    power = dict()

    # misc variables
    con = float()
    control = dict()
    function_interval = None

    def start_sim(self):...

    def stop_sim(self): ...

    def update_cons(self, *args):...

    def update_text_box(self, value):...

    def blink(self, *args):

        if self.ids.led1.base_color == [0, 0, 0, 1]:

            self.ids.led1.base_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]

        else:

            self.ids.led1.base_color = [0, 0, 0, 1]

class ConfigWidget(Widget):  # Class that contains logical and graphical info from config page

    def analyser(self):  # Tests if its possible to initiate by calling com_test
        global comunic
        if comunic.com_test(test_port=self.ids.comm_input.text):
            self.ids.error_msg.text = ""
            port_name = self.ids.comm_input.text
            comunic.open_port(port_name)

            Clock.schedule_interval(read_state(), 1 / 40)
            # Ignore the above
            Clock.schedule_interval(PrincipalWidget().blink, 0.5)


            self.possible = 1
. . .
```

kv.file:

```
<Gerenciador>:

    ConfigPage:
    PrincipalPage:

<PrincipalPage>:

    name: "two"

    PrincipalWidget:


<ConfigPage>:

    name: "one"

    ConfigWidget:

<PrincipalWidget>:
    .
    .
    .

    # Control panel
    FloatLayout:
        ...

        # easy access btns
        BoxLayout: ...

        # time management
        GridLayout: ...          

        # Controls
        GridLayout: ...

    Led:
        id: led1

<ConfigWidget>:
    canvas: . . .

    BoxLayout:
        pos: (root.width-self.width)/2, (root.height-self.height)/2
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: 15

        Label: . . .

        TextInput: . . .

        RoundedBtn:
            back_rgb: [0.7, 0.7, 0.7]
            size_hint_y: None
            bold: True
            border_radius: [self.height/2]
            text: "Apply"
            
            on_release:
                root.analyser()
                if root.possible == 1: app.root.current = "two"


    Label:
        id: error_msg
        text: ""
        color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        pos: (root.width-self.width)/2, root.height/5

<Led@Widget>:
    size: 50, 50

    base_color: [0, 0, 0, 1]

    canvas:
        Color:

            rgba: self.base_color

        RoundedRectangle:

            size: self.size
            radius: [self.width/2]
            pos: self.pos
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has something to do with the screens and screenmanager, at least that's what i think(not that experienced in Kivy), also with how i was addressing the method i wanted to call.

I was trying to execute it with a `Clock.schedule_interval` that was called in my method `analyser` that would run my `blink` method.

The way you should do it is by firstly given the screen tha has your method. With that you should call it as `app.root.get_screen("<NameOfScreen>").ids.<ScreenId>.<method>` even if what you're trying to do is a `Clock.schedule_interval`. In case the latter, create a method that calls it. Then you'll just have to put that app.... in you screen changer trigger.

My code is now like this:
Kv file:

```
<Gerenciador>:

    ConfigPage:
    PrincipalPage:

<PrincipalPage>:

    name: "dois"

    PrincipalWidget:
        id: PrcWid


<ConfigPage>:

    name: "um"

    ConfigWidget:

<PrincipalWidget>: ...

<ConfigWidget>:

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: root.width, root.height
            pos: 0,0

    BoxLayout:  # Gráficos do widget da página de configuração
        pos: (root.width-self.width)/2, (root.height-self.height)/2
        orientation: "vertical"
        spacing: 15

        Label:
            text: "Type port"
            font_size: 15

        TextInput:
            id: comm_input
            multiline: False
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30

        RoundedBtn:
            back_rgb: [0.7, 0.7, 0.7]
            size_hint_y: None
            bold: True
            border_radius: [self.height/2]
            text: "Aplicar"
            on_release:
                root.analyser()
                if root.possible == 1: app.root.current = "dois"
                if root.possible == 1: app.root.get_screen("dois").ids.PrcWid.schedule()

# Note how i call it
# My analyser method alters possible. Not important the condition

    Label:
        id: error_msg
        text: ""
        color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        pos: (root.width-self.width)/2, root.height/5
```

Other classes not changed

Python side:

```
class PrincipalWidget(Widget):
    # Dict responsible for getting the specified powers from json file
    power = dict()

    # misc variables
    con = float()
    control = dict()
    function_interval = None

    def start_sim(self):. . .

    def update_consumo(self, *args):. . . 

    def update_text_box(self, value):. . .

    def schedule(self):

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.blink, 0.5)

    def blink(self, *args):
        print("blink")

        if self.ids.led1.base_color == [0, 0, 0, 1]:
            print("should've changed color")
            self.ids.led1.base_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]

        else:
            print("should've changed color")
            self.ids.led1.base_color = [0, 0, 0, 1]

class ConfigWidget(Widget):

    def analyser(self):  # Tests if its possible to initiate by calling com_test
        global comunic
        if comunic.com_test(test_port=self.ids.comm_input.text):
            self.ids.error_msg.text = ""
            port_name = self.ids.comm_input.text
            comunic.open_port(port_name)

            Clock.schedule_interval(read_state(), 1 / 40)

            self.possible = 1

        else:
            self.ids.error_msg.text = "Invalid Port!"
            self.possible = 0
```